# Embed Lightning component in Leaflet map popup?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I'm using Leaflet inside a Lightning component to map locations of a number of entities. I'd like to display a Lightning component in the Leaflet popup for each entity, and I'm struggling to connect the dots using `$A.createComponent`.

I thought that the correct pattern was to use `component.find()` on the parent component (holding the Leaflet map) to get a reference to a `div` within the popup as a component and inject my dynamically created component using `div.set('v.body');` However, I'm clearly missing something, since I get `undefined` back from `component.find()` and the `aura:id` attribute doesn't render to the DOM on the popup's `div`. I'm not clear on whether my mistake is in understanding Leaflet's popup rendering or dynamic component creation.

Here's a skeleton of my code:

```
    body = '<div aura:id="<GENERATED ID>"></div>';

    m = L.marker([data.lat, data.lng], {'title': title })
         .bindPopup(body)
         .addTo(map)
         .on('popupopen', function(e) {
            $A.createComponent('POPUP_COMPONENT_NAME', { COMPONENT ATTRIBUTES }, 
                function(cmp, status, errorMessage) {
                    if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
                        var div = component.find(<GENERATED ID>);
                        var body;

                        body = div.get('v.body');
                        body.push(cmp);
                        div.set('v.body', body);
                    } else {
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Sorry but you can't dynamically generate `aura:ids`. Generally you can embed your dynamic id as a `data-` attribute and access it that way (using regular javascript dom methods).

Comment: @CasparHarmer Thanks for clarifying that. I'm not sure how to use the element references to insert a dynamically generated component, though. I know it can be done in Lightning Out using $Lightning.createComponent, but the $A version doesn't take an ID or element reference.